# Changing of the numbering of parts in beamer

Tags: beamer, numbering, parts

I want to change the part numbering in beamer.

I tried the following:

```
\renewcommand*{\thepart}{\arabic{part}}
\renewcommand{\thepart}{\arabic{part}}
```

but without any success.  The Roman numbering stays.

What would be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should modify the `part page` template; it is defined as:

```
% Part page: default

\defbeamertemplate*{part page}{default}[1][]
{
  \begin{centering}
    {\usebeamerfont{part name}\usebeamercolor[fg]{part name}\partname~\insertromanpartnumber}
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=16pt,center,#1]{part title}
      \usebeamerfont{part title}\insertpart\par
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  \end{centering}
}
```

and it uses `\insertromanpartnumber`. There is a simple method to get arabic numebers: change the previous command into `\insertpartnumber`.

Quoting the `beameruserguide`:

> The following commands are useful for this template:
>
> - \insertpart inserts the current part name.
> - \insertpartnumber inserts the current part number as an Arabic number into a template.
> - \insertpartromannumber inserts the current part number as a Roman number into a template.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\setbeamertemplate{part page}
{
  \begin{centering}
    {\usebeamerfont{part name}\usebeamercolor[fg]{part name}\partname~\insertpartnumber}
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=16pt,center]{part title}
      \usebeamerfont{part title}\insertpart\par
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  \end{centering}
}

\begin{document}
\part{Review of Previous Lecture}
\frame{\partpage}
\section[Previous Lecture]{Summary of the Previous Lecture}
\subsection{Topics}
\frame{...}
\subsection{Learning Objectives}
\frame{...}

\part{Today's Lecture}
\frame{\partpage}
\section{Topic A}
\frame{\tableofcontents[currentsection]}
\subsection{Foo}
\frame{...}
\section{Topic B}
\frame{\tableofcontents[currentsection]}
\subsection{bar}
\frame{...}

\end{document}
```

---

To change the label *Part* into *Theme* for example, you should proceed like this:

```
\renewcommand{\partname}{Theme}
```

Comment: Thank you that works, but now I seem not to be able to change the name from "Part" to say "Theme"

Comment: I guess you can remove `\partname` with `Theme` in the template `part page`. Did you try?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: yes, now I see that the previous comment is a bit misleading. I'll edit the answer to accomplish this task.

Comment: I got an answer to the change of the name see: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65608/babel-beamer-problem-refuse-name-change-to-part#comment139772_65608