# babel, beamer problem: refuse name change to part

Tags: beamer, babel

I wanted to change the name in my beamer slide from Part to Theme.

So in the Google BOK if found:

```
\renewcommand*{\partname}{Theme}
```

I could not get to work.  Then I start to switch off (%) everything that I added and found that:

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
```

is the holder of the key.

An MWE:

```
\documentclass[compress,infolines,smaller]{beamer}

%\usepackage[english]{babel}
\useinnertheme[shadow=true]{rounded}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

\renewcommand*{\partname}{Theme}


\begin{document}

\AtBeginLecture{
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
}

\part{Title}
\begin{frame}<beamer>
\partpage
\end{frame}
\section{test1}
\begin{frame}
Test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to get passed this?

Comment: http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=latexwords

Comment: TNX! I just moved the \renewcommand*{\partname}{Theme}
 to after \begin{document} and now it works perfect!

Comment: You can leave it in the preamble using `\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand*{\partname}{Theme}}`.

Comment: @Louis: as long as you use only one language putting the definition after `\begin{document}` will work. But in general it is better to get used to the babel syntax `\addto\captionsenglish{...}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I very few times write documents in more than one language, its a messy job to do as the spellcheckers intensify my grey hair.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I will try that as well, because I have a "preamble" document that I keep for each of the subjects that I teach and in there I store my standard settings for that subject and the university at which I teach it.

Comment: @Ulrike Please write a short answer, possibly including Gonzalo's `\AtBeginDocument` hint.

Comment: @lockstep: But Louis didn't accepted my answer. I would always use `\addto\caption...` and not move the `\renewcommand` behind `\begin{document}` or in a `\AtBeginDokument`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has obviously to do with how `babel` manages the "fixed tags" such as `\partname`.

It stores them in a macro called `\captions<language>` (in this case `\captionsenglish`) that is executed as part of

```
\selectlanguage{<language>}
```

or

```
\begin{otherlanguage}{<language>}
```

The `\selectlanguage` command for the main language of the document is issued  together `\begin{document}`. Thus your `\renewcommand` does nothing, because it's overridden by what's done by `\selectlanguage{english}`.

`babel` has a provision for this:

```
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\partname}{Theme}}
```

is what you're looking for.

---

Also `\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\partname}{Theme}}` would work *unless* you load `babel` with more than one language and issue some `\selectlanguage` command in the document. To make an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[italian,english]{babel}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\partname}{Theme}

\begin{document}
\part{X}
Something in English.

\selectlanguage{italian}
Parole in italiano.

\selectlanguage{english}
\part{Y}
End in English.

\end{document}
```

would result in

> **Theme I**
>
> Something in English.
>
> Parole in italiano
>
> **Part II**
>
> End in English.

This wouldn't happen with the `\addto\captionsenglish` approach.

Comment: Sorry for waiting so long.