# How to change "part" to "chapter"

Tags: amsart, parts, naming

I am using `amsart` document class.

The structure order in amsart is Part -> Section -> subsection -> subsubsection

My question: how may I modify `\part` so that latex would show "Chapter" instead of "Part"?

---

I tried the idea provided below but it does not work in my latex... :(

Please find below an minimum working example and a screen shot

```
\documentclass[english, reqno, 9pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{geometry}            % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. There are lots.
%\geometry{letterpaper}                   % ... or a4paper or a5paper or ... 
%\geometry{landscape}                % Activate for for rotated page geometry
%\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}    % Activate to begin paragraphs with an empty line rather than an indent
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,color}
\usepackage{mathrsfs,dsfont, comment,mathscinet}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{enumerate,esint}
\usepackage{natbib}


\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{picinpar}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{amsaddr}


\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}




%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\renewcommand{\partname}{Chapter}
\newcommand{\chapter}{\part}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


%----------------------------Special for this paper ------------------------------





\title{test}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\thispagestyle{empty}%this command remove the page number at the title page

\tableofcontents


\chapter{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Related: [`babel`, `beamer` problem: refuse name change to part](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65608/5764)

Comment: i'm not sure why you can't use `amsbook` which comes with `\chapter` already defined.  of course, the `amsbook` `\chapter` behaves like a normal book, and starts a new page.  i guess you just want everything to continue on without page breaks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adjust `\partname` and make yourself a macro called `\chapter` so that things make sense conTeXtually (...see what I did there...?):

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\renewcommand{\partname}{Chapter}
\newcommand{\chapter}{\part}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}

\end{document}
```

If you're loading [`babel`](http://ctan.org/pkg/babel), then you can use

```
\newcommand{\chapter}{\part}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\partname}{Chapter}}
```

or

```
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\partname}{Chapter}}
```

to update `\partname`.

Comment: I don't know why but it does not work in my case. I provide an minimum working example above. Could you have a look?

Comment: @JumpJump: Oh, I see, now you have a huge "minimal" example that loads a bunch of packages... including [`babel`](http://ctan.org/pkg/babel) - the culprit. I'll update my answer.

Comment: and yea, my thesis does contains a lot packages...