# Changing the Part label in a Beamer Presentation

Tags: beamer, parts

I want to change the "Part" sectioning header in a presentation from "Part I", "Part II" etc. to "Lesson 1", "Lesson 2" etc.  I'll also use "Lesson I", "Lesson II" etc if this is easier.  Any suggestions for doing this?

Thanks,

Walt Paczkowski

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a start based on [babel, beamer problem: refuse name change to part](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65608) (surely not perfect).

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

% use the name of babel: english
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\partname}{Lesson }}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\part{Part A}
\frame{\partpage}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{TOC}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Section A}
\begin{frame}
Test
\end{frame}

\section{Section B}
\begin{frame}
Test
\end{frame}

\part{Part B}
\frame{\partpage}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{TOC}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Section A}
\begin{frame}
Test
\end{frame}

\section{Section B}
\begin{frame}
Test
\end{frame}

\part{Part C}
\frame{\partpage}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{TOC}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Section A}
\begin{frame}
Test
\end{frame}

\section{Section B}
\begin{frame}
Test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly for getting "Lesson" rather than "Part."  How do I get the Arabic numerls (1,2,3) as opposed to the Roman numerals?

Comment: @Walt Please ask a new question. And consider upvoting or accepting the answer if it solved your problem.