# Placing insert-like commands in tikz node for beamer theme

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I'm following this question [Link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65560/changing-of-the-numbering-of-parts-in-beamer) to change the numbering of parts in my beamer theme. Now I want to place the command \insertpartnumber into a tikz node to place it in the exact position on the part page. However, the placing seems not working and the node always appears on the south.west corner (shift page to current position) of the part page. Before I make a working example I'd like to ask, if in general it is not possible to place insert-like commands into a tikz node for table of content pages?

The code looks something like this:

```
\defbeamertemplate*{partpage}{mytheme}
{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\tikzset{shift={(current page.south west)}} 
\node[anchor=west] (1,1) {\insertpartnumber};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\AtBeginPart{%
\frame{
\usebeamertemplate{partpage}
\partpage
}
```

I made a simple work around:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\setbeamercolor{part name}{fg=black}

\defbeamertemplate*{part page}{test}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,shift={(current page.south west)}]
\useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
\fill[color=yellow] (1,1) rectangle (2,2);
\draw (1,1) -- (3,3);
\node[xshift=3cm,yshift=2cm] (2,2) {\insertpart}\par; %x and y shift do the job!!!
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\AtBeginPart{%
\frame{
\usebeamertemplate{part page}
}}

\begin{document}
\part{Part 1}
\begin{frame}
Test
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You may need the `current page` node.

Comment: Thx for your comment. I tried, but it doesn't change anything